# Redux -> How can I save multiple objects in a single store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I have an app that, whenever I push a button it adds objects to the redux store, the thing is that whenever I press that button the store doesn't really hold the items that I've added but it actually just replaces them, how can I make it so that when I press the button it saves the object inside of it, then on the second click it adds the next object and so on.
Here's my code:
That's where my button is:

```js
{item.map(product => (
  <div>
    <h1>{product.name}</h1>
    <h2>{product.Price}</h2>
    <button onClick={() => buyProduct(product)}>
      Buy
    </button> 
  </div>
)}
```

That's where my buyProduct function is:

```js
const buyProduct = (item) => {
  store.dispatch({type:"buy", payload: item})
}
```

And that is all of my redux code:

```js
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'buy') {
    return action.payload;
  } else if (action.type === 'Decrease') {
    return action.payload
  }
  
  return state;
}

const store = createStore(reducer, 0)

store.subscribe(()=>{
  console.log('Store is now: ', store.getState())
})

const buyProduct = (item) => {
  store.dispatch({type:"buy", payload: item})
}
```

How can I also make it so that I could loop over the store's stored objects

Comment: What is the initial state, the action and the expected new state after the action dispatched?

Comment: well by default I believe it is undefined, so whenever I press that button it adds the item object to the store, that is done in a map function I've made and it basically loops over the following stateHook:  `const [item]=useState([{name:'Blue',Price:540},{name: 'Red',Price: 600}])`
thing is that whenever I console log it after the button has been clicked it only shows the last instance of the products in item but i want it to show all instances, that have been created when I clicked the button

Answer (score 0):

in the reducer you should add the new data to the current data. if your cart-data is an array of objects, you should push the new product object to the array. for example :

```
if(action.type==='buy')
{
    return {...state, cartArray: [...state.cartArray, action.payload] };
}
```

and the same logic in the `Decrease` action.

Comment: I definitely see the logic here, but `...state.cartArray` throws an error claiming that it isn't iterable. Why is that?

Comment: it mean that it is not array or object.. if you can show your initial state code it may help to help you

Comment: This is where I keep my products:
`const [item]=useState([{name: 'Blue',Price: 540},{name: 'Red',Price: 600}])`
Excuse my foolishness I have just began learning redux

Comment: sincerely i think the better thing to do is just continue learning :) because there are many things that are not accurate in your code. good luck